# How to decode lua files and resource files that are protected from Frida and IDA64?

Tags: ida, android, frida, lua

I am trying to decrypt Lua files from an Android game "The Sea Road: Fate Assembly" ([APK download link](https://apkpure.com/the-sea-road-fate-assembly/com.fateassembly.gp)). It uses Cocos2d-x, but it's encrypted, maybe with AES encryption.

With Frida, the game will crash when I hook it. It also crashes in IDA64 when I hook it. Have someone an idea and when I search for the sig: GuoSig, I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: Have you [searched](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=xxtea_decrypt) our site?

Answer (score 1):

As with other cocos2dx games there's a function called `xxtea_decrypt` which you can see being called via IDA, Ghidra, etc; - the third parameter is the key, `s`:

[image: Decrypt function]

Going to `unk_117E730`:

[image: Key]

The key is as follows (I was able to decrypt the first file I tried):

```
09 08 07 AB 01 02 03 AB 04 05 06 AA BB CC AB AC
```

Comment: what xxtea_decrypt are you using to decrypt the files?

Comment: I used https://github.com/xxtea/xxtea-php/tree/master. Remember to ignore the `GuoSig` bytes..

Comment: thx works perfect
do you know what pkm files are ?

Comment: Nope, never heard of that.