# decode lua files cocos2dx and protected from Frida and IDA64 for hooking

Tags: ida, android, frida

I want to decode the lua and other resources files. But i cant find the key when i use frida or ida 64 it crash before the game start.
Game is here https://megamonglobal.com/
https://imgur.com/88Habwu

Comment: Have you followed the steps listed in my answer to your previous question ([here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32315/how-to-decode-lua-files-and-resource-files-that-are-protected-from-frida-and-ida))? Often you don't even need to hook into the game.